# How to declare Object within $scope AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and I'm trying to create a template where I have an implicit object that calls **test** and inside **test** I have an array that I want to repeat when I call a function inside my Controller, but I'm getting **undefined error** when I'm trying do push an object inside the array.

Here is the example of my code:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller"MyController">
    <input ng-model="person.name">
    <button ng-click="createPhone()">
    <div data-ng-repeat="phone in person.phones">
        <input ng-model="phone.number">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
//app.controller...
    $scope.createPhone(){
        var phone = {number: '123456789'};
        $scope.person.phones.push(phone);
    }
```

I'm getting:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'phones' of undefined.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Well you haven't defined $scope.a, at least not from your code snippet. can you share your whole controller code please? Also your createB function is not defined correctly, it should follow the syntax of $scope.createB = function() {}

Comment: In my controller I really haven't defined the $scope.a, but how can I declare with the b object?

Comment: The html you have posted is incorrect. Where is the ng-controller? Are you using "controller as"?  Why are you mixing data- prefixes in? Where is "test" defined? Have you defined `$scope.a` and `$scope.b`? I would post your whole controller so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Well you need to define $scope.a so you can assign a b property to it. Your code is confusing, what exactly are you trying to achieve, what sort information are you trying to display in the UI?

Comment: Im guessing you are just trying to do something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/hm53pyjp/2/

Comment: Ready, I edited my code again.

Comment: @haxtbh Is it, but with **b** inside **a**

Comment: Have updated it to match changes to your question code - http://jsfiddle.net/hm53pyjp/3/

Comment: Yeeeaaaah, it's right @hax!!!! Put the link in answer!!!

Comment: Answer has been added.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are going to want to do something like this:

Example can be seen here - http://jsfiddle.net/hm53pyjp/4/

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <input ng-model="person.name" />
            <button ng-click="createPhone()">Create Phone</button>
        <div ng-repeat="phone in person.phones">
            <input ng-model="phone.number" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

Create a `person` object that you can add things to and create a function to push objects to it.
So here I have created a `person` with the properties `name` and `phones`. I have give the `name` property a value of "User" and the `phones` property an array of numbers. In this case I have just populated one number to get started.

The function then gets called on the `ng-click` and simply pushes an object to the existing `phones` array.

As you push the objects to the array the `ng-repeat` will start to update the inputs on the page.

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.person = {
        name : "User",
        phones : [{number: 12345}]
    };

    $scope.createPhone = function () {

        $scope.person.phones.push({
            'number' : '111-222'
        });

    };
}
```

Comment: I have a similar issue, I have solved the issue with your post, but now I want to add methods to phone, How could I do it? are there any way to place phone logic in a different controller?